# Big O domination

Tags: big-o

Im studying for a test and a practice problem states:

```
True or False:
O(n^3 + n^2) dominates O(n^4)
```

Do we count `O(n^3 + n^2)` as `O(n^5)`? If so it does dominate.

Comment: Where does n^3 + n^2 = n^5?

Comment: This is like GRE math level trickery. Designed to get you to do the seemingly simplest operations immediately and lead you to the wrong result. No, you do not add those and even if you did, n^3 + n^2 != n^5... n^3 * n^2 = n^5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, we do not. If you add two functions `O(n^3)` and `O(n^2)`, you have `O(n^3)` asymptotic behavior, as the `O(n^2)` itself is "dominated" by the `O(n^3)`. In other words, `O(n^3 + n^2)` is equivalent to `O(n^3)`, not to `O(n^5)`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `O(n^3)` dominates `O(n^2)`, so `O(n^4)` dominates `O(n^3)`.
which means `O(n^3)` does not dominate `O(n^4)`.

So your answer is **False**